# Angular ng-model for number type

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to generate dynamic form JSON API.  I have different types of fields in my form.

I am using ng-model to generate form elements from JSON data.

```
<input ng-model="answer[id]" type="number" name="user[{{id}}]">
```

Here is my JSON data:

```
{"1" : "John",
 "2": "600001"
 }
```

It works fine for text type input element but not for number.

I understand the issue, its because of JSON data is in string. I am trying to set string value to number field.

I don't want to change the type in API, but I want to handle it in angular side.

How can I type cast the string to integer and set it to number field ?

I would like to set the value "600001" to number type input element.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to cast your string to integer , as

```
parseInt(yourStringValue, 10);
```

Comment: From controller we can parse the value to integer.  I want to do it in view. Because my JSON data is too large.

Comment: I want to want to set the value  "600001" to number field. I don't want to parse this value from controller. Is there any way to convert an set the value to number field while using ng-model ?